# Azure ML Studio saved plots have boxes instead of characters

Tags: r, plot, utf-8, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

**Context & Update:** I've rewritten this post to reflect latest findings (problem as yet unresolved)

Using Azure Machine Learning Studio to run an "Execute R script" task. Using a compute cluster, which shuts down after running the pipeline (so no console access but can save files as logs to view after shutdown). Environment is Ubuntu and R version it loads is 3.5.1 (Session Info). I am creating plots `png` and then saving them into an Excel workbook `openxlsx`, and finally saving and retrieving this in Azure file storage. This file management is done with the `azuremlsdk` library

**The issue I am having is that the characters on the plots are "squares" or "boxes", also seen referred as "glyphs"**

[image: png imported into excel clip]

I've provided a code sample (although not completely reproducible as it requires Azure) to show the simple test I am running

```
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
imageName <- "testplot.png"
png(imageName)
plot(price ~ carat, data = diamonds, main = "Price vs Carat")
dev.off()
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "testplotsheet", gridLines = TRUE)
insertImage(wb, "testplotsheet", imageName)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = xlName, overwrite = TRUE)
```

sessioninfo & capabilities outputs

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /azureml-envs/azureml_6ff64eff0a652bbe0bb1d84fc0884554/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /azureml-envs/azureml_6ff64eff0a652bbe0bb1d84fc0884554/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tibble_3.0.1      ggplot2_3.3.0     azuremlsdk_1.10.0 openxlsx_4.2.5   
[5] dplyr_0.8.5       jsonlite_1.6.1    reticulate_1.12  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8       magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_1.0.0 munsell_0.5.0   
 [5] colorspace_1.4-1 lattice_0.20-41  R6_2.4.1         rlang_1.0.1     
 [9] tools_3.5.1      grid_3.5.1       gtable_0.3.0     withr_2.2.0     
[13] ellipsis_0.3.0   assertthat_0.2.1 lifecycle_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4    
[17] Matrix_1.2-18    zip_2.2.0        purrr_0.3.4      vctrs_0.2.4     
[21] glue_1.4.0       stringi_1.4.3    compiler_3.5.1   pillar_1.4.3    
[25] scales_1.1.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3 

          name value
1         jpeg  TRUE
2          png  TRUE
3         tiff  TRUE
4        tcltk  TRUE
5          X11 FALSE
6         aqua FALSE
7     http/ftp  TRUE
8      sockets  TRUE
9       libxml  TRUE
10        fifo  TRUE
11      cledit FALSE
12       iconv  TRUE
13         NLS  TRUE
14     profmem  TRUE
15       cairo  TRUE
16         ICU  TRUE
17 long.double  TRUE
18     libcurl  TRUE
```

From another post on stackoverflow: **Boxes show up when there is a mismatch between Unicode characters in the document and those supported by the font. Specifically, the boxes represent characters not supported by the selected font.**

Results from various things I have tried:

`Cairo` : can't install because missing "cairo.h"

`par(family ="Ubuntu Mono")` (used *after* runing `png` as suggested) didn't change anything

`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8')` (suggested on ms forum) didn't change the LC settings, but also does not seem supported based on checking available locales on the system `system("locale -a", intern = TRUE)`

```
[1] "C"       "C.UTF-8" "POSIX"
```

I've seen a suggestion to use `iconv`, but don't know how to incorporate this into the code above. How could I use this or is it irrelevant?

This seemed significant:

**`sysfonts` is not installed, and can't install it due to missing `zlib`. This also prevents me from installing `showtext`**

- do `png` and other graphics device rely on `sysfonts` to create characters in images?
- is this  why the `family` and `type` global settings or parameters in `plot`, `png` etc do nothing?

Are there any fonts available I wondered? `font.families`, `font.files`, `font_families` & `font_files` all blank or error

I did manage to locate some `*.ttf` files on the system, (not in any recognised fonts folder location), so thought perhaps I can load them or force R to use them for the `png` device

`extrafont` tried to use this to add fonts.  however because `font_import` function requires responding to a y/n prompt, not sure if it loads. I saved the output for `fonts()` but blank, so probably not

- Any other way to force `png` to use one of these `ttf` font files?

`pdf` this actually works! I can get characters to display saving the same output in `pdf`, does this use its own fonts? This seems to imply that it should be possible to get characters to display on `png`

At this point I am seeing if our Engineers can access a different compute because all these problems seem to stem from an outdated/inadequate R and Ubuntu environment. However, if there are any other ideas to get these characters to display, I welcome suggestions!